# Display image after upload to a folder into PDF using PHP

Tags: php, file-upload, multipartform-data

I can upload the image to a new folder, but the main things is need to display it out from that folder to PDF. Then I am using FDPF, but then I get an error message when displaying:

```
"Uncaught Exception: FPDF error: Can't open image file: Tulips.jpg "
```

But when i echo the $img it display. Then i add on $img in pdf->Image($img) it wont work it appear above message error.

Here is what I have try to code `htmltopdf.html`

```
var _validFileExtensions = [".jpg", ".jpeg", ".bmp", ".gif", ".png"];    
function ValidateSingleInput(oInput) {
    if (oInput.type == "file") {
        var sFileName = oInput.value;
         if (sFileName.length > 0) {
            var blnValid = false;
            for (var j = 0; j < _validFileExtensions.length; j++) {
                var sCurExtension = _validFileExtensions[j];
                if (sFileName.substr(sFileName.length - sCurExtension.length, sCurExtension.length).toLowerCase() == sCurExtension.toLowerCase()) {
                    blnValid = true;
                    break;
                }
            }
             
            if (!blnValid) {
                alert("Sorry, " + sFileName + " is invalid, allowed extensions are: " + _validFileExtensions.join(", "));
                oInput.value = "";
                return false;
            }
        }
    }
    return true;
}
function handleFileSelect(event) 
{
    console.log(event)
    var input = this;
    if (input.files)
    {
        var filesAmount = input.files.length;
        for (i = 0; i < filesAmount; i++)
        {
        var reader = new FileReader();
        console.log(reader)
        reader.onload = (function (e)
        {
            var span = document.createElement('span');
            span.innerHTML = ['<img class="thumb" src="',e.target.result, '" title="', escape(e.name), '"/><span class="remove_img_preview"></span>'].join('');
        document.getElementById('preview').insertBefore(span, null);
        });
        reader.readAsDataURL(input.files[i]);
        }
    }
}

$(document).ready(function(){     
    // Listen to click event on the submit button
    $('#submit').click(function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        var myform = document.getElementById("form");
        var fd = new FormData(myform);
        $.ajax({
            url:"upload1.php",
            type:"POST",
            data:fd,
            //dataType: 'json',
            processData: false,
            contentType: false,
            cache: false,       
            success:function(data){ 
                alert("Success Insert!");
            },
        });
        });     
$('#fileToUpload').change(handleFileSelect);    
//preview image and remove
$('#preview').on('click', '.remove_img_preview',function ()
{
    $(this).parent('span').remove();
    $("#fileToUpload").val("");
    });
});

</script>
<style>
div.relative {
  position: relative;
  top: -300px;
}
#bottom{
    position: relative;
    right:    0;
    bottom:   0;
}

.thumb
{
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    margin: 0.2em -0.7em 0 0;
}
.remove_img_preview
{
    position:relative;
    top:-25px;
    right:5px;
    background:black;
    color:white;
    border-radius:50px;
    font-size:0.9em;
    padding: 0 0.3em 0;
    text-align:center;
    cursor:pointer;
}
.remove_img_preview:before
{
    content: "×";
}
table,th, td {
  border: 1px solid black;
  border-collapse: collapse;
}
th, td {
  padding: 5px;
  text-align: left;
}
textarea {
  width: 100%;
  height: 300px;
  padding: 12px 20px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  border: 2px solid #ccc;
  border-radius: 4px;
  background-color: #f8f8f8;
  font-size: 16px;
  resize:none;
}

table.menu {
    border: 1px solid black;
    border-collapse: collapse;
    width: 10%;
    float:right;
}

</style>
<body>

<form action="generate_pdf.php" method="POST" id="form">
    <input type="submit" value="Send" id="submit" name="submit"><input type="reset" value="Clear">
    <input type="file" name="fileToUpload[]" id="fileToUpload" onchange="ValidateSingleInput(this);" multiple = "multiple" style="display: none;">
    <input type="button" value="Browse..." onclick="document.getElementById('fileToUpload').click();" />
    <input type="submit" value="PDF">
    <div id="preview"></div>
</form>

</body>
</html>
```

Here is the `upload1.php`

```
<?php
require 'config.php';

$year = date("yy");
$year = substr($year, -2);
$month = date("m");
$key = "KM".$year.$month;
$total = count($_FILES['fileToUpload']['name']);
$sql = "SELECT * FROM images WHERE id LIKE '$key%' ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 1";
$result = $conn->query($sql);

//GET NEW RUNNING NUMBER BY CHECKING DATABASE
if ($result->num_rows > 0) 
{
    // output data of each row
    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc())
    {
        $number = sprintf('%03d',substr($row['id'], -3)+ 1) ;
        $ans = $key.$number;
    }
} 
else
{
    $ans = $key."001";
}

$target_dir = "D:/XAMPP/htdocs/new3/new3/uploads/" . $ans;

if(!file_exists($target_dir))
{
    mkdir($target_dir,0777,true);
}
$sql = $conn->query ("INSERT INTO images (id) VALUES ('$ans')");

$allowed = array('gif', 'png', 'jpg','xlsx','pdf','doc');
$ext = pathinfo($total, PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
if (!in_array($ext, $allowed)) {
    echo 'error';
}

for( $i=0 ; $i < $total ; $i++ )
{
if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["tmp_name"][$i], $target_dir."/".$ans."-".$_FILES["fileToUpload"]["name"][$i]))
  {
    
    echo "The file ". basename( $_FILES["fileToUpload"]["name"][$i]). " has been uploaded."."<br>";
  } 
  else 
  {
    echo "Sorry, there was an error uploading your file.";
  }

}

?>
```

Here is the `generate_pdf.php` that i have try:

```
    <?php
$img=$_FILES["fileToUpload"]["name"][0]; 
    
   echo $img;

require 'fpdf181/fpdf.php';
$pdf = new FPDF();
$pdf->AddPage();

$pdf->SetFont('Arial','B',10);
$pdf->Image($img,NULL,NULL,0,0,'PNG');
$pdf->Output();
?>
```

I don't know whether I wrote it correctly or not? Or just need to call back the path where image is stored and display it out? Myself already brainstorming, don't know how it works. Can anyone help? Maybe this is a duplicate questions but I can't even find any related things, just can found how to retrieve from database.

Answer (score 0):

First problem is that your `<form>` tag is missing the `enctype="multipart/form-data"` attribute.

As for the PHP error, `$_FILES["fileToUpload"]` is an array, so `$image=$_FILES["fileToUpload"]["name"]` should change to `$_FILES["fileToUpload"]["name"][0]` (assuming you want the first file). So `generate_pdf.php` should start with:

```
$image=$_FILES["fileToUpload"]["name"][0];
```

Comment: It says " Warning: fopen(download (1).png): failed to open stream" then, "  Uncaught Exception: FPDF error: Can't open image file: download (1).png "

Comment: my image is call download(1).png

Comment: Shouldn't `$pdf->Image($image)` be `$pdf->Image($img)`? Also, if you want the file that was uploaded, you should be using `$_FILES["fileToUpload"]["tmp_name"][0]`.

Comment: And now it say "Fatal error: Uncaught Exception: FPDF error: Image file has no extension and no type was specified: C:/xampp/htdocs/test/uploads/ in C:\xampp\htdocs\test\fpdf181\fpdf.php:271 Stack trace: #0 C:\xampp\htdocs\test\fpdf181\fpdf.php(877): FPDF->Error('Image file has ...') #1 C:\xampp\htdocs\test\generate_pdf.php(11): FPDF->Image('C:/xampp/htdocs...') #2 {main} thrown in C:\xampp\htdocs\test\fpdf181\fpdf.php on line 271"

Comment: It sounds like FPDF  can't determine the type from the temporary filename that PHP assigns the uploaded file. Try adding those additional parameters: `$pdf->Image($img, NULL, NULL, 0, 0, 'jpg')`.

Comment: added and its say "Fatal error: Uncaught Exception: FPDF error: Can't open image file"

Comment: You'll have to update your question to show your code.

Answer (score 0):

After i have amend some of it the error come out is "Fatal error: Uncaught Exception: FPDF error: Can't open image file"
This is the code file i have amend call generate_pdf.php

```
$image=$_FILES["fileToUpload"]["name"][0]; 
$img="C:/xampp/htdocs/test/uploads/".$image;

require 'fpdf181/fpdf.php';

$pdf = new FPDF();
$pdf->AddPage();

$pdf->SetFont('Arial','B',10);
$pdf->Image($img, NULL, NULL, 0, 0, 'png');
$pdf->Output();
```

Comment: `$_FILES["fileToUpload"]["tmp_name"][0]` is the fully qualified filename of the file, so you need to change `$img="C:/xampp/htdocs/test/uploads/".$image` to `$img=$_FILES["fileToUpload"]["tmp_name"][0]`. You don't need the `$image` variable at all.

Comment: @kmoser Sry for late reply i just amend what u have told the error says this "Uncaught Exception: FPDF error: Can't open image file: Tulips.jpg "

Comment: Please edit your original question so show your latest code. Do not post updates as answers.

Comment: `$img=$_FILES["fileToUpload"]["name"][0]` should be `$img=$_FILES["fileToUpload"]["tmp_name"][0]`

Comment: @kmoser thanks alot it works. So if let say i need to display multiple image to pdf so i need a loop for the array variable??